# How to call a relationship who contains another relationship - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm trying to make a site where users have projects, and I'm trying to make a kind of "activity wall" to improve the communication of each project, so this "activity wall" messages belong to the project and the Messages inserted in it belong to the user too. So, I created the migration below:

```
Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('content'); //the message
    $table->string('file'); //if has a file
    $table->integer('user_id')->constrained(); //to make the relationship with the Users table
    $table->integer('projeto_id')->constrained();//to make the relationship with the Projetos (Projectc) table
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And in Projeto Model, I create the relation.

**Projeto.php**

```
public function message()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
}
```

The same to

**User.php**

```
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
}
```

And this to

**Message.php**

```
public function projetos()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Projeto::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

But the problem is: When I try to get the Messages table with the Project relationship.

```
public function index($id)
{
    $projeto = Projeto::findOrFail($id);

    $messages = $projeto->message;        
}
```

I can't get the User relationship to get the owner username of the message to return to my view. What is the better way to do this?

Comment: the messages is linked to both user and project. when you get the messages, you can get user or project both like this such as : message->user->name

Comment: FYI your relationship method names are incorrect, should be `Projeto::mesages()` and `Message::projeto()`. Because message only has one projeto, and projeto has many messages.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `with`, to prevent `n query`:

```php
public function index($id)
{
    $projeto = Projeto::with('message', 'message.user') // this will get the relation `message`, and `user` from the message
        ->findOrFail($id);
    $messages = $projeto->message;        
}
```

Comment: You can also use the `route-model binding : public function index(Projeto $projeto) {...}` and use `$projeto->load(['message.user'])` to get the relationship. You don't really need to define the `message` alongside `messasge.user` since `message.user` will include the message and the user